# Download a file from web into a specific location in PC

Tags: vb.net, webclient

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim imageAddress As String = String.Empty
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim fileReader As New WebClient()

        Dim proxy As IWebProxy = New WebProxy("proxy adress", port number)
        proxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("network userid", "network password")

        imageAddress = "http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-esign-pdf-file-tutorial-ue.pdf"

        filename = imageAddress.Substring(imageAddress.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)

        If Not (System.IO.File.Exists("D:\" + filename)) Then
            fileReader.DownloadFile(imageAddress, "D:\" + filename)
        End If
    Catch ex As HttpListenerException
        MsgBox("Error accessing " + imageAddress + " - " + ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error accessing " + imageAddress + " - " + ex.Message)
   End Try
End Sub
```

The above code throws an error 407:proxy authentication required. I do not seem to understand the problem with my code. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the proxy credentials are correct? This is what the `407` error suggests. In what line the error occurs?

Comment: @TasosK. yes the credentials are correct.error message is the second catch block. Do you have any alternative way of achieving the desired result?. if yes please do share

Comment: I tried your code without using a `WebProxy` and it worked. So comment the two lines that use the `proxy` variable.

Comment: @TasosK. the same error persists. i dont know whats the issue :(

Comment: have u solved this issue?